# How to read a .xls file in Matlab using fscanf

Tags: matlab, matrix, scanf

I am attempting to read a  .xls file into Matlab. I am prohibited from using built-in functions such as xlsread(), textread() and readable(). I am allowed to convert the .xls file to other formats if easier and I have tried the code below using data.txt but to no avail.

I am allowed to use the basic 'fopen', 'fscanf', 'fread' functions. However, I can't seem to figure out how to implement them correctly.

A mock version of my the data is shown below....

```
Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
  1     2     3      4     5.5   6    Fox
  2     3     4      5     6.7   8    Cat
  18    12    56     3     20.2  9    Dog
```

and so on for around 400 rows

Currently, my code looks like this

```
fileID = fopen('data.xls', 'r');
fgetl(fileID);
data = fscanf(fileID, '%d %d %d %d %f %d %*s');
fclose(fileID);
```

I am attempting to remove the columns header row and just retrieve the first 6 columns. I want to ignore the text column at the end.

This code returns an empty matrix 'data[]'

What am I doing wrong?

**Updated code and dataset**

I have implemented MichaelTr7's answer on the full dataset but it still only copies the first line of the document? Below is a more accurate depiction of the dataset. I did not include it above for simplicity sake but now I believe it to be needed

```
Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4  Col5   Col6  Col7  Col8  Col9
  18    8    307    130   3504   12    70    1   chevrolet chevelle malibu
  2     3     4      5    6.7    8     70    1   buick skylark 320
  18    12    56     3    20.2   9     70    1   amc ambassador dpl
  NA    4    133    115   3090   40    70    2   ford torino
```

code...

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
Headers = string(fgetl(fileID));
Format_Specification = '%d %d %d %d %d %f %d %d %*s';
Array_Size = [8 Inf];

Output_Array = fscanf(fileID,Format_Specification,Array_Size);
Output_Array = Output_Array.';

fclose(fileID);
```

Ouput_array is now equal to [18,8,307,130,3504,12,70,1]

Comment: `fscanf` doesnt deal with a header, so you need to use a different function. BTW, you are reading a `xls` there, did you meant to read the `txt`?

Comment: What would you recomend? I can use either the .xls or .txt, whichever is easier. I thought I would leave it as .xls

Comment: May be save the xls file as csv file first (xls files have a complex binary format).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen this worked, kind of. It now returns the first value in the first column so '1'. Any clue how I would then get it to carry on for the rest of the file?

Comment: Are any other functions allowed? Like `split()` and `fgetl()`.

Comment: @MichaelTr7 I believe I am allowed to fget1(). The purpose of the exercise is to use as few built in helper functions as possible and try to write own code instead. Unsure on split() but let’s just say yes haha

Comment: @Seb Haha, got ya. I've implemented a script that uses `fgetl()`, `split()` and `size()`. Though `size()` can probably be changed by implementing a while loop edited in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation in progress:**
This method uses a `.txt` (text file) and `scanf()` with a specific format configured. Below and the specifications:

```
Format_Specification = '%d %d %d %d %f %d %*s';
```

Denoted as `%d` are the terms read as integers. 
Denoted as `%f` are the terms read as floats.  
Denoted as `%*s` are the string terms ignored. The asterisk `*` indicates which terms to be ignored.

```
Array_Size = [6 Inf];
```

This `Array_Size` indicates how the read in format should be read in column-wise. Since there are six terms the array will have a height of 6. The other dimension is `Inf` (infinite) to accommodate any length of `.txt` (text file). By transposing the `Array_Size.'` the format can be shown row-wise as expected/to conform to the format in the original `.txt` (text file).

[image: Output Results]

### data.txt

```
Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
  1     2     3      4     5.5   6    Fox
  2     3     4      5     6.7   8    Cat
  18    12    56     3     20.2  9    Dog
```

### Script:

```
clear;
clc;
fileID = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

%Grabbing the first line with headers and ignoring%
Text = string(fgetl(fileID));


Format_Specification = '%d %d %d %d %f %d %*s';
Array_Size = [6 Inf];

Output_Array = fscanf(fileID,Format_Specification,Array_Size);
Output_Array = Output_Array.';

fclose(fileID);

Output_Array
```

---

### Edit: Implementation Using `fgetl()`, `split()` and `size()`

[image: Output Results 2]

### data.txt

```
Col1  Col2  Col3   Col4  Col5   Col6  Col7  Col8  Col9
  18    8    307    130   3504   12    70    1   chevrolet chevelle malibu
  2     3     4      5    6.7    8     70    1   buick skylark 320
  18    12    56     3    20.2   9     70    1   amc ambassador dpl
  NA    4    133    115   3090   40    70    2   ford torino
```

### Script:

```
clear;
clc;
fileID = fopen('data.txt', 'r');

Text = string(fgetl(fileID));

%Running for loop till end of file termination "-1"%
Line_Index = 1;
while(Text ~= "-1") 
    
    Text = string(fgetl(fileID));
    if (Text ~= "-1")
    Lines(Line_Index,1) = Text;
    end

    Line_Index = Line_Index + 1;
end


fclose(fileID);

Output_Array = [];
[Number_Of_Lines,~] = size(Lines);

for Row_Index = 1: Number_Of_Lines

Line = split(Lines(Row_Index,:));
Line = Line(2:9)';

Output_Array(Row_Index,:) = Line(1,:);


end
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Slowly making more progress. This does indeed work on the dataset provided in the question above but for some reason, it doesn't work on the dataset I am trying to actually use. It only copies the first line! For simplicity sake, I was trying to not to upload the full dataset but as it appears to be affecting the answer, I have now added it to the question